# Active workbook reverting to "thisworkbook" without prompt

Tags: vba, excel

```
Workbooks("The One Sheet.xlsx").Activate
MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Name  'Returns "The One Sheet.xlsx"
Worksheets("One Sheet").Activate

MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Name 'Returns "The One Sheet.xlsx"
RwCnt = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))
MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Name 'Returns the sheet that contains the code
```

Does anyone know what could be calling the other workbook into focus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what is calling up the other WB into focus. But it is best practice to explicitly define references to workbooks

```
Sub SheetCode()
    Dim wbOne As Workbook
    Dim RwCnt As Long

    Set wbOne = Workbooks("The One Sheet")
    wbOne.Activate
    RwCnt = wbOne.ActiveSheet.Range("A" & wbOne.ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    MsgBox "The last row is " & RwCnt
End Sub
```

Hope that helps, Caleeco

Comment: Thanks!  I still don't understand what was causing it, but this provided a workable solution.